# Search results list navigation broken from "view all favorites" link

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, bookmarks, navigation-arrows

### I noticed a bug and a difference in behavior for navigating your favorites.

#### Steps to reproduce the bug:

1. Sign in to stackoverflow jobs
2. **Click on the [view all favorites...](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?isfavorite=True) link in the sidebar**
3. **Click on one of the results**, I tried this with both the 1st (featured) and the 2nd entries

   - [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/115383/demandware-software-engineering-manager-120k-crossover?a=CH97AImc4gg&so=p&offset=0&isfavorite=True), note the `isfavorite=True` is present in the query parameters
4. **Click on the "#next-job" link** at the top right

   - [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/115147/help-teachers-connect-to-students-to-transform-makemusic?offset=1&salaryCurrency=USD), **note that the `isfavorite=True` is missing from the query parameters**
5. Repeat (4) one or more times, you will **eventually land on a job not located in the favorites list**

#### Note that the following steps **result in the correct behavior** using the search instead of the link

1. Sign in to stackoverflow jobs
2. Click [search jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs)
3. Enter `favorite:true` under "Keywords" and click "search"
4. **Click on one of the results**, I tried this with both the 1st (featured) and the 2nd entries

   - [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/119142/full-stack-c-sharp-javascript-developer-assuresign?a=DXiUh2sl2EM&searchTerm=favorite%3Atrue&so=s&offset=0) **note that the `searchTerm=favoirite:true` is used instead of the `isfavorite=True`**
5. **Click on the "#next-job" link** at the top right

   - [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/119608/architect-remote-usa-or-canada-phreesia?offset=1&searchTerm=favorite%3atrue&salaryCurrency=USD)  note that the `searchTerm` is included
6. Repeat (5) and it will continue correctly through the list of favorites

#### Observations

So, there is apparently a **difference in implementation between the `isfavorite` and the `searchTerm` query parameters used in the #next-job link.**  Thankfully there's a workaround, but this can be annoying as its very easy for someone to fall into this bug by clicking on the favorites link and trying to go through the list.  Additionally, it may be **worth considering a 'favorite' checkbox to the Keywords drop down** to expose the correct behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed.

Thank you for your detailed report!

Comment: Great, verified on my end as well.  Quick work!